# What happened to Agu's mother?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, beasts-of-no-nation

In the movie [*Beasts of No Nation*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1365050/) (2015) what happened to Agu's mother? Was Agu able to find her?

It is not mentioned in the movie. Is there any explanation in the book which the movie is based on?

Answer (score 1):

Agu mistakes a woman for his lost mother, clinging to her in a sudden — and given the scene, shocking — regression to childishness. But when he realizes he was wrong, his bitter disappointment and remaining moral sensibility curdle into a dreadful outcome. Agu shoots the woman while she is being raped. Maybe it’s a kindness, given the fate that potentially awaits her. Maybe it’s an act of vengeance, the woman’s only guilt being that she is not the mother Agu still longs for.